# How MSMQ works with Hangfire. Can anyone explain the flow?

Tags: msmq, hangfire

Can anyone explain how will message be received by MSMQ queue and how hangfire will process that request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default SQL server tables are used to store jobs in queue and the server processing the jobs polls the table to check for new jobs and starts processing them. 
This involves a latency i.e when a new job is queued it will wait for at least the polling interval to be processed again.

When MSMQ is used for job queuing, new jobs are queued for execution in MSMQ queue and they are immediately available for processing as a subscription model is used in this case instead of a polling one. So if you want to reduce background job latency use this instead of sql server.